# Drawbacks of using NULL as function argument

Tags: r, function, null, arguments

Consider `geom_smooth()` from `ggplot2` where we can set whether we want to see confidence intervals (`se` argument) and how wide the intervall is (`level` argument). For example:

```
df <- data.frame(x= rnorm(100), y= rnorm(100))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x ,y)) + geom_smooth(se= TRUE, level= .95)
```

I see no need for two separate arguments: If we set some `level` we obviously want to see the confidence intervalls. So in this case the `se` argument is redundant. On the other hand, if we choose `se= FASLE` the `level` argument is redundant. Therefore, to me it is intuitive to summarize both information in one argument. So my definition of the function would be something like that:

```
my_smooth <- function(lev, ...){
if(is.null(lev)){
geom_smooth(se= FALSE)
} else{
geom_smooth(se= TRUE, level= lev)
}
}
```

So in `my_smooth()` there is one argument and we can either decide not to see confidence intervals by choosing NULL or we put in the level we want to see. Of course, we could add `lev= .95` as default if we want.

In my opinion this method is quite straightforward and avoids paradox situations like `geom_smooth(se= FALSE, level= .95)`. Are there drawbacks in using `NULL` in a function argument as an option as done in `my_smooth()`? I.e. is it bad practice to use NULL as "do not realize this argument"?

**EDIT**

Question is not about `geom_smooth()`. I work on a package where I want to use NULL this way. It is just easier to explain with a well-known function what I mean.

Comment: You still have an `if` and 2 arguments: your function first tests  `is.null(lev)` and if it's `TRUE` sets `se` to a value, if not sets it to another value. You test an argument's value to decide on the other, nothing is gained. Moreover, a user might sometimes want SE bands and other times not but always with the same level. The `se` value would be passed as a variable and the `level` remain constant.

Comment: The above comment is a matter of opinion, as is the question. Maybe it's a question more suited for the package maintainer.

Comment: @Rui It is not about geom_smooth. I work on a package where I want to use NULL this way. It is just easier to explain with a well-known function what I mean.

Comment: `NULL` as the default argument value has its uses. It avoids referring to a missing argument. You can also test `missing(arg)`.

Comment: Rui "nothing is gained." To me as a lazy user it is easier to save the second argument. R does the if else part without my effort. You write "other times not but always with the same level.": When does someone want to set se to FALSE but to provide some level? That would answer my question since it would provide a drawback of using just one argument.

Comment: As for the last part of the comment, "when does someone want to set se to FALSE but to provide some level?", the answer is "never". But what if you don't know beforehand if you want confidence bands? 95% is a frequent confidence level, suppose you set it once and for all and then call the function setting only `se` or assigning a variable the value `FALSE/TRUE` and then use the *variable* in the function.

Comment: And it's not unfrequent to have examples like `geom_smooth`, some arguments only make sense if others are set to a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `my_smooth` function *requires* the user to specify `lev`.  The `geom_smooth` approach allows the user to accept the defaults for the `se` and `level` arguments, or just change one of the defaults.

The definition of the `se` and `level` arguments is also easier to document.  Your `lev` argument means two things:  whether to plot the band, and how to plot it.  You're lucky that in this case the choice of "don't plot it" doesn't require a numerical parameter, but in other situations where one argument represents a binary choice, other arguments may apply to both situations.  The `geom_smooth` choice is consistent with these other situations in having parameters have clear meanings.

The fact that one parameter is sometimes irrelevant is a small cost:  you don't pay (mentally) for each parameter, you pay for each decision.  You're still making two decisions, so your solution is no cheaper.

There are other situations where having one parameter is better than two.  For example, R allows you to specify the default for one parameter based on the value of another.  The `dgamma/rgamma` etc. functions use this to allow you to specify the `rate` or `scale` of the distribution, but not both (since `rate*scale = 1`).  This is thought to be convenient because some people are used to working with one and other people with the other, but I think it just confuses everyone, makes the documentation more complicated, and makes people wonder why `rnorm` doesn't allow you to specify the variance instead of the s.d.?

Comment: @mental cost: number of decisions is same but number of argument names to remember doubles. I work on a package and for one function the mental cost is to remember 10 instead of 5 argument names.